# Is it possible to use an Internet Explorer plugin as a control in a WinForms project?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, plugins, browser

As the topic asks. Is it possible for me to use any plugin written for Internet Explorer in my WinForms project without having to use the WebBrowser control?

(I want to be able to use the IBM AFP viewer in my own viewer app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paticular plugin is a part of IBM **Web Interface** for Content Management, it is not supported outside Internet Explorer. You probably want to look though IBM's documents to find if there is any other interface. The AFP2PDF viewer looks like a good choice for an http client with an PDF viewer.